# Underline journal, conference names in reference

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style, underline

I tried a lot to find out how to underline journal, conference, or venue names in my reference. But, I am unable to find it. Please check the reference check, the author highlights the venue name.

Reference
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.12033.pdf

[image: Like ECCV, CVPR]

Comment: It's not clear to me that the division of labor is supposed to be between you (author, right?) and the journal (IEEE transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence, right?) Has the journal furnished instructions on how to prepare the manusript for submission? Are you really required to underline the contents of `journal` fields? Please advise.

Comment: There are some authors that put underline on venue name so the reviewers can understand the better venue and make the final decision. Sometimes, this happens

Comment: Did the provided answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I think I know of no style that applies underlining to titles in the bibliography. Many styles use italics, which in LaTeX can be implemented with `\emph`. If you load the package `ulem`, `\emph` will produce underlining instead of italics.

This is what happened here. If you download the source code from https://arxiv.org/format/1912.12033 (or more specifically https://arxiv.org/e-print/1912.12033) and rename the downloaded file to `1912.12033.tar.gz`, you will find that the paper uses the bibliography style

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

which uses `\emph` and would usually give italic titles. The file also loads

```
\usepackage{ulem}
```

in the preamble so that `\emph` produces underlining.

This is very likely not what the IEEE wants on submission, so I suggest you do not load `ulem` and do not try to emulate the output from that paper.